# jQuery task, get the value of a select html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem that i can't solve... I have this jQuery code:

```
v=$('#sede').val();
$('#sede').change(function() {
    console.log('valor de v:'+v);
});
```

and this html select:

```
<select name="se" id="sede" size="1">
  <option value="1">Primer Elemento</option>
  <option value="2">Segundo Elemento</option>
  <option value="3">Tercer Elemento</option>
  <option value="4">Cuarto Elemento</option>
</select>
```

the problem is the variable v only shows the first item value when i click in the select, no matters the second, third or any item...

Answer (score 5):

You should get the value of `<select>` on change event:

```
var v;
$("#sede").change(function() {
    v = this.value;
    console.log("valor de v:" + v);
});
```

Comment: @LuParra That's not the worst case ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to reset the value of `v` after the `select` is changed. Like this:

```
var v;
$('#sede').change(function() {
  v = $('#sede').val();
  console.log('valor de v:'+v);
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/WwVzU/) with alert for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Why call the selector again? You've already got the element (via `this`)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point, and I'd go even further by using the pure JS `this.value`, as VisioN did in his answer. I was just focusing on solving the issue he presented.